# cx_freeze freezed python program doesn't run - no time to see the error message on executing

Tags: python, cx-freeze

so I made that python program using several module including os, zipfile, time, datetime, shutil, shelve and ftplib. I froze it with cx_freeze, it won't run on the target machine (but it run on mine). I'm super new to cx_freeze, but I've poked around a bit and I suspect it's a module ot found error. Trouble is, when I execute the exe on the target machine the window doesn't stay open long enough for me to catch the error message so I can't even narrow down the issue to try and solve it. Any idea on how I could deal with it?

Comment: Is it a console program? Have you tried executing the exe from the console?

Comment: Yeah it is, I'm a freaking dummy. I should have thought about this in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

Executing the exe from the console works out fine. Thanks.